# Validating subexpression in Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle12c, regexp-substr

Oracle 12cR1

I have a column with lengthy strings like below

```
:Key1:Value1:Key2:Value2:Key3:Value3:Key4...…..
```

The keys are unique numbers. The values are any string value which can even be a number same as any other key. If I give a key i must get its corresponding value. For example,

```
lengthy_str_col := ':101:abc:12:43:43:101.4:4:bus'
```

For getting the value for the key, 43, I tried the following.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(lengthy_str_col,'(:([^:])+)(:[^:]+)') FROM DUAL;
```

This gives me the first key-value pair `':1:abc'`. Now as I know that 43 is the third key, I used

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(lengthy_str_col,'(:([^:])+)(:[^:]+)', 1, 3, 'i', 4) FROM DUAL;
```

to get the value `101.4` for the key `43`.

But a required key can be at any random position. Is there a way to get the value for any given key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(':101:abc:12:43:43:101.4:4:bus', '^(:[^:]+:[^:]+)*?:43:([^:]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 2) as Result from dual
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QHaRwG/1) and [this regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3A%5B%5E%3A%5D%2B%3A%5B%5E%3A%5D%2B)*%3F%3A43%3A(%5B%5E%3A%5D%2B)):

[image]

**Explanation**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(:[^:]+:[^:]+)*?` - zero or more, but as few as possible, occurrences of two repetitions of `:` and 1+ chars other than `:`
- `:43:` - a key in between colons
- `([^:]+)` - Group 2 (the result): 1 or more chars other than `:`

Comment: Assuming the key must be non-NULL but the payload (the value) may be NULL, it may be a bit safer to change the second `[^:]+` (but not the first one) into `[^:]*` - in both places that is used. Also, if eventually this solution is to be used with different inputs, `43` can be replaced with a bind variable.

Comment: @mathguy I agree. I just followed OP logic when choosing the quantifier.